# iterating over function and storing all of the results in a variable?

Tags: python, function, variables

this is probably a really simple question, but when you iterate over a function, how do you store all of the results in a variable, as whenever i do it, the variable only stores the first result?

```
for a in hometimeline['ids']:
   b = oauth_req(
    'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=1&user_id=%s'%a,
   '###########################################',  (these are just tokens)
   '###########################################')
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a list

```
b = []
for a in hometimeline['ids']:
   b.append(oauth_req(
      'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=1&user_id=%s'%a,
      '###########################################',  (these are just tokens)
      '###########################################'))
```

or a dictionary

```
b = {}

for a in hometimeline['ids']:
   b[a] = oauth_req(
      'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=1&user_id=%s'%a,
      '###########################################',  (these are just tokens)
      '###########################################')
```

Answer (score 1):

use a list comprehension:

```
b=[oauth_req("some_parameters_here%s",a) for a in hometimeline['ids']]
```

Comment: This list comprehension is redundant.  I think you're looking for `[function(x) for x in hometimeline['ids']]`